# "Suppose we have a collection of blog posts where each document was/is a post"

Tags: verbs, tenses, sequence-of-tenses, past-vs-present

I found this in a book:

> Suppose **we have** a collection of blog posts where each document **was** a post.

Shouldn't it be:

> Suppose **we have** a collection of blog posts where each document **is** a post.

Or is it correct as it is?

Comment: Should be "I **found** this in a book." Either one is correct. There is no sequence of tense rule in English; people use any combination they like that makes sense. By the way, don't try to correct books written by native speakers; they can and do make mistakes, but if you're still learning the language, you can't possibly know enough rules to correct them. Just accept it as another unknown phenomenon; don't assume it's a mistake.

Comment: @JohnLawler Question corrected. No, I was not trying to correct it, was just wondering if this one was correct as I felt it sounded somehow weird to me.

Comment: No, it's normal. The subordinate clause is in another universe of discourse, so there isn't any continuity of tense.

Comment: The latter sounds good. Just lose the "where" and substitute "in which." Call it a personal preference of mine. "Where" works better when pointing to a physical location, as in, "Meet me where Poplar Street and Main Street intersect." Or, "Paris is where I proposed to my wife-to-be." That sort of thing. "Where" also tends to be a habit with some people, as is the "due to the fact that" locution, instead of simply "that." Compare, "I was upset due to the fact that Jim spoke out of turn," versus "I was upset that Jim spoke out of turn."

Comment: @JohnLawler: Maybe it's just Latin _conditioning_, but as a matter of style, I really don't like that first sentence.

Comment: See, this is the difference between personal preferences and grammar. When there is a choice to make between two synonymous constructions (and there are many many such to make every day), many people create a preference for one, or possibly use the choice to mark a distinction they want to make (but possibly others might not). This is why nobody talks the same, or writes the same -- at least after they've learned the language. It's style, but it's not grammar. Grammar is what you absolutely have to do, what you absolutely can't do, and what choices you have with the other stuff.

Comment: Some would argue for: *Suppose we had a collection of blog posts in which each document **were** a post.*

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Why doesn't somebody go ahead and post an answer for the sake of completeness?

Answer (score 2):

"Suppose we have a collection of blog posts where each document is a post."

This is correct. As per my knowledge "have" shows present tense and "was" is past tense....So "is" sounds correct there.